# How to add databind into hyperLink of aspx page

Tags: c#, asp.net

```
View Bookings
```

I want something like

```
<pre>
<asp:HyperLink ID="h" runat="server" NavigateUrl='~/test.aspx?id=Bind("instructor_id")'> View Bookings</asp:HyperLink>
</pre>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it this way:

```
NavigateUrl='<%# "~/test.aspx?id=" + Eval("instructor_id") %>'
```